# add new column with not null

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to add a new column to a table as below but it is throwing me error.

```
   ALTER TABLE YBC.POLICY_NON_FIN ADD COLUMN PAY_FREQ CHARACTER(2) NOT NULL;
```

> [Error] Script lines: 26-27 ------------------------
>    In an ALTER TABLE statement, the column "PAY_FREQ" has been specified as NOT NULL and either the DEFAULT clause was not specified or was specified as DEFAULT NULL.. SQLCODE=-193, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.67.28

So I cannot add not null during alter statement.  Is it mandatory to add as default ?

Comment: so, the table already has data, right?. And then you are adding a column, that cannot be `NULL`, but you didn't gave it a default value. So what value should the column have?

Answer (score 3):

specify a default, otherwise it would be `null` when you add it.

```
ALTER TABLE YBC.POLICY_NON_FIN 
    ADD COLUMN PAY_FREQ CHARACTER(2) NOT NULL default '';
```

Comment: Once you've added the column, you can drop the default value: `ALTER TABLE YBC.POLICY_NON_FIN ALTER COLUMN PAY_FREQ DROP DEFAULT`